# cutom ehcache evict policy with spring

Tags: spring, ehcache, evict

If we want to custom evict policy besides LRU LFU FIFO, the way docs recommanded is to implement interface Policy then set MemoryStoreEvictionPolicy like:

```
manager = new CacheManager(EHCACHE_CONFIG_LOCATION);
cache = manager.getCache(CACHE_NAME);
cache.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy(new MyPolicy());
```

but if I used spring, use @cacheable and xml files like

```
<bean id="cacheManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" ></property>
</bean>


<!-- cacheManager -->
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

how can I inject my own policy in spring way?

thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be best to implement your own class that sets the eviction policy on the cache when Spring initializes.

For example:

```
public class MyEvictionPolicySetter implements InitializingBean {

    public static final String CACHE_NAME = "my_cache";

    private CacheManager manager;
    private Policy evictionPolicy;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        Cache cache = manager.getCache(CACHE_NAME);
        cache.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy(evictionPolicy);
    }

    public void setCacheManager(CacheManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public void setEvictionPolicy(Policy evictionPolicy) {
        this.evictionPolicy = evictionPolicy;
    }
}
```

And then in your Spring config:

```
<bean id="cacheManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" ></property>
</bean>

<!-- Specify your eviction policy as a Spring bean -->
<bean id="evictionPolicy" class="MyPolicy"/>

<!-- This will set the eviction policy when Spring starts up -->
<bean id="evictionPolicySetter" class="EvictionPolicySetter">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="evictionPolicy" ref="evictionPolicy"/>
</bean>
```